# Recycler view select item and save the selection

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have this Recycler view and its working good , but now i need when the user click into item in the Recycler highlight the item and intent to another activity , and when back to the Recycler show the item that selected still highlight and just one item can select ? any idea ?

this is my recycler view adapter

```
public class ScreenRecyclerAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScreenRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Context context;
int image_list[];
public ScreenRecyclerAdapter(int[] image_list, Context context){
    super();
    this.image_list = image_list;
    this.context = context;}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.screen_items, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(image_list[position]).into(holder.image_view_screen_item);
   }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return image_list.length;
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView image_view_screen_item;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image_view_screen_item = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_screen_item);
        image_view_screen_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, ImagePager.class);
                context.startActivity(i);
                image_view_screen_item.setSelected(true);
            }
        });
    }}}
```

and this is the Activity of recycler

```
public class ScreensActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView image_recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager image_recyclerViewlayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter image_recyclerViewadapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screens);
    int image_list [] = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};
    image_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.image_recyclerView);
    image_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    image_recyclerView.setSelected(true);
    image_recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    image_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(image_recyclerViewlayoutManager);
    image_recyclerViewadapter = new ScreenRecyclerAdapter(image_list, this);
    image_recyclerView.setAdapter(image_recyclerViewadapter);}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's divide the question into 3 sub-parts: 
**1. Highlight recycler-view item on tap** 
You can implement `recycler-view item listener` in multiple ways, as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick). Once you implement it, change `view` background-color from there  like:

```
 @Override 
 public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
     view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eee"));
     //
  }
```

**2. Redirect to another activity on tap** 
Within `onClick` method you may start a new activity like:

```
@Override 
 public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
     // check for item
     Intent intent = new Intent(mContext);
     startActivity(intent);
  }
```

**3. When back to the Recycler-view show the selected item as highlighted** 
Make a `public static var`. When you click an item - which will redirect user to another `activity` assign that item id to that  `static var` , now in `onBindViewHolder` always check if the list-item id as same as the `static var` if it's `true` then change background of the `view` as in part 1. 
 *Make sure not to finish current `activity` after starting a new `activity`.*

Comment: its working Highlight recycler-view item , but step 3 i cant understand it !

Comment: when user tap on an `item` save that item `id` either in `SharedPreferences` or in static variable... within  `getView()` or `bindHindler()` check for that item `id`, if itemId is equal to that last-selected-item-id then change background-color like <br />    ` if (viewHolder.itemId==myItemId){view.backgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eee")); }`

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on an item, save its position and pass it to the other activity.
Once returning to the original activity return the saved value with it and in onBindViewHolder method if the position equals the saved value highlight the item.